# Tabular: Specify break suggestions to avoid underfull messages

Tags: tables, line-breaking, columnbreak

Consider the following MWE (the dashes are required). This is producing `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}}
     aa--bb--cc--dd--ee--ff--gg--hh--jj   
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, if I add spaces, this error disappears.

My questions are:

- How can I **turn off autofill** (enlarge spaces to fill the whole line) for a column or cell?
- How can I mark double/triple dash as default break suggestion across my entire doc (like space)?
- (if this is not possible) How can I **specify break suggestions** in text without spaces (`aa--bb--cc`). E.g. I tried `aa--\break bb` and `aa--\allowbreak{}bb` but that did not work (still underfull).

Error disappears with (but add unwanted space):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}}
     aa -- bb -- cc -- dd -- ee -- ff -- gg -- hh -- jj   
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not clear to me. What do you mean exactly by a break suggestion?

Comment: With Break suggestion I mean a point in a word (which is not in a dictionary/babel) where Latex might break it. So eg `aa-\allowbreak{}bb`  to allow latex to break `aa-bb`  in `aa-` and `bb`.

Comment: There's already `aa\-bb`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space has to go somewhere:

- `\raggedright` puts it at the end of the line. Also `\RaggedRight` of package `ragged2e` can be used.
- The following example also used a kind of flexible dash to make it longer or shorter to make it easier for TeX to get a justified paragraph. (Experimental, since I do not know the function of the dashes in this context.)
- Package `microtype` adds a little flexibility for the letter widths (HZ algorithm), which gives TeX's line breaking algorithm more room for better line breaks. Also, the optical protrusion feature might help a little.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\flexdash}[1][--]{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}% Width of dash as natural width
    \sbox2{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis to approximate
    %  the vertical position of the dash
    \nobreak
    \leaders\hrule height\dimexpr\ht2 + .1pt\relax
      depth\dimexpr-\ht2 + .1pt\relax
    \hskip\wd0 plus .4\wd0 minus .2\wd0 %
    \penalty\exhyphenpenalty
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{2cm}}
      aa--bb--cc--dd--ee--ff-gg--hh--jj
    \end{tabular}

    \medskip

    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}}
      aa\flexdash bb\flexdash
      cc\flexdash dd\flexdash
      ee\flexdash ff\flexdash
      gg\flexdash hh\flexdash jj
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Awesome Heiko this really helps me